# Table Header Not Visible in UI5 Application

Tags: javascript, model, sapui5

I have created a table, but the header is not getting displayed. Inside my component, I am reading an OData entity and storing it inside a JSON Model. This JSON Model is then used to bind the header column texts.

I have attached the table output image for reference:

[image]

Header View.xml:

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="NPAWRMA.controller.header" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
    <App id="idAppControl">
        <pages>
            <Page title="NPAW RMA Report">
                <content>
                    <l:VerticalLayout>
                        <Table id="table" growing="true" items="{odata>/RmaPercRevColSet}">
                            <columns>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="CBU" id="CbuShortNameColumnTitle"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label01}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label02}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label03}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label04}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label05}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label06}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label07}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label08}"/>
                                </Column>
                            </columns>
                            <items>
                                <ColumnListItem type="Active" press="onPress">
                                    <cells>
                                        <Text text="{odata>CbuShortName}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc01', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State01}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc02', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State02}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc03', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State03}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc04', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State04}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc05', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State05}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc06', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State06}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc07', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State07}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc08', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State08}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc09', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }"  state="{State09}"/>
                                    </cells>
                                </ColumnListItem>
                            </items>
                        </Table>
                        <Table id="table1" growing="true" items="{odata>/RmaPercRevColSet}">
                            <columns>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="CBU" id="CbuShortNameColumnTitle1"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label01}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label02}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label03}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label04}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label05}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label06}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label07}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column>
                                    <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label08}"/>
                                </Column>
                            </columns>
                            <items>
                                <ColumnListItem type="Active" press="onPress">
                                    <cells>
                                        <Text text="{odata>CbuShortName}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc01', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State01}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc02', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State02}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc03', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State03}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc04', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State04}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc05', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State05}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc06', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State06}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc07', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State07}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc08', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State08}"/>
                                        <ObjectNumber number="{ path: 'odata>NpiPerc09', formatter: '.formatter.numberUnit' }" unit="%" state="{State09}"/>
                                    </cells>
                                </ColumnListItem>
                            </items>
                        </Table>
                    </l:VerticalLayout>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </pages>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Component.js:

```js
sap.ui.define([
 "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
 "sap/ui/Device",
 "NPAWRMA/model/models"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models) {
 "use strict";

 return UIComponent.extend("NPAWRMA.Component", {

  metadata: {
   manifest: "json"
  },

  /**
   * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
   * @public
   * @override
   */
  init: function() {
   //"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.local.com";
   //"Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-KEY";
   UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
    debugger;
   var sModel = this.getModel("odata");
   sModel.setSizeLimit(999);
   var oJson1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
   sModel.read("/Labels1Set('0')", {
    success: function(oss) {
     oJson1.setData({
      Label: oss
     });
    },
    error: function(oss) {}
   });
   this.setModel(oJson1, "Labels");
               
    // enable routing
   this.getRouter().initialize();
   // set the device model
   this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, the table header is actually displayed. The first column header (which is statically bound) is rendered correctly.

[image: annotated table screenshot]

So the problem seems to reside with the binding paths or the model content itself.
I am not completely sure what you obtain inside the `sModel.read("/Labels1Set('0')", ...)` success callback, because it depends completely on how you defined your OData model. You should check if the indeed has all these `Label01` to `Label08` properties.

Another thing that I can spot is that you are actually setting the result in the `/Label` binding path, but then you are using the `/Labels1/LabelXX` binding path(i.e. the path starts with `Labels1` instead of just `Label`). TO fix this, you should adjust the success callback of the read call:

```
success: function(oss) {
    oJson1.setData({
        Labels1: oss
    });
}
```

Or, maybe more readable would be to just do `oJson1.setData(oss)` and then simply remove the `/Labels1` prefixes from the binding paths.

Comment: By modifying the success callback function it is working fine now.